# select persian character in sql stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server database and I set collation to `persian_100_CA_AI`.

In my table, I have id and name (Id = `int` and Name = `Nvarchar`)

Now I want select from this table with this stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CarName] 
    @Name  NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        SELECT Id 
        FROM Car 
        WHERE Name LIKE N'%'+@Name+'%'
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT -100
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

When my name not have a space like this ('ماشین') this works correctly, but when my name has a space like this ('ماشین من') this does not work and does not return value :(

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: what happens if you execute an exact search instead of a `LIKE`? does a name with a space is handled correctly when performing an exact search? also your syntax looks like MSSQL's one: maybe the mysql tag is not correct?

Comment: could you please post here some sample data because it is working on my SQL 2012

Comment: @tinka,thank's for your help.i found reason problem.The problem goes back to 'ی' character,in any column that i have 'ی' .this query not work.how i can fix it ?

Comment: @tinka,for example,when my column name value is 'ماشین' not return value ,because conain 'ی' and when my column name value is 'ماشن' return value

Comment: @jon it is also giving me expected records